# Dynamic instrumentation tools which support reverse execution

Tags: binary-analysis, dynamic-analysis

I am trying to analyze some execution crash information, and to better identify the root cause of memory access error, I would like to `reverse execute` the program from the crash point.

For example, to identify the root cause of memory access error below, I would like to reversely execute from the third line, and by leveraging some data flow analysis techniques, I should be able to identify the root cause at the first line.

```
mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax       <---- root cause is at memory -0x18(%rbp)
add    %rdx,%rax
mov    (%rax),%eax            <--- crash when reading (%rax)
```

So here is my question, is there any dynamic analysis tool/debugger that can support reverse execution? I prefer `Pin`, but I am not aware that `Pin` can do this..

Comment: In previous versions of Pin, there was API for [checkpoint/reexecution](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/publicity/pin/docs/31933/Pin/html/group__CHECKPOINTING.html); but they are not supported in recent versions. They are instead moved to a more complete framework, called [PinPlay](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/program-recordreplay-toolkit?language=en).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a Look at http://rr-project.org The website says it supports reverse execution. Yet, I am not a 100% sure if this is exactly the same you are talking about.

> rr also provides efficient reverse execution under gdb. Set breakpoints and data watchpoints and quickly reverse-execute to where they were hit.

See also the gdb record and replay feature [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Reverse-Execution.html#Reverse-Execution)

> On some platforms, gdb provides a special process record and replay target that can record a log of the process execution, and replay it later with both forward and reverse execution commands.

Comment: [rr](http://rr-project.org/) should be definitely tried, I am indeed excited by this implementation. I wish its API more clear to use.

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions of Pin, there was APIs for [checkpoint/re-execution](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/publicity/pin/docs/31933/Pin/html/group__CHECKPOINTING.html); but they are not supported in recent versions. They are instead moved to a more complete framework, called [PinPlay](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/program-recordreplay-toolkit?language=en).

You can also implement an ad-hoc `reverse execution` using existing API(s) (e.g. Pin_ExecuteAt, Pin_SaveContext, etc). The naive idea is to track the memory writing and store the original value. I have implemented actually such an [engine](https://github.com/tathanhdinh/PathExplorer/blob/windows_version/version_1/src/base/checkpoint.cpp) (sorry for the self-advertisement).

Comment: Many thanks for your information. Could you elaborate more on how to use your engine? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to IDA, you can use the [trace replayer](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/replayer/trace_replayer.pdf). It doesn't exactly support reverse execution, but I wrote it with the idea to help in the problem you have: check why a crash happened by replaying recorded executions traces. The program is not executing but rather replaying the execution trace, however, in most cases, that is more than enough.